# XNPV Excel function on Mac : not working?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook

trying to use XNPV (Excel) function on a Mac ;  for some reason this does not work yielding only ERROR message (exact same exercise on PC no problem) ;  error shows that through the (correctly entered) formula i would be referring (erroneously of course) to some far away empty cell...

help anyone ? 
Francis 
(PS running Dutch version of Excel, but that should not matter i guess)

Comment: (1) It might help if you told us what version of Excel you're using. (2) It might help if you told us what error message you're getting (translated into English, as appropriate). (3) Does the "exact same exercise" work on a PC *running **the Dutch version of** Excel*? You know that function names change according to the local language, right? (4) What does "referring (erroneously of course) to some far away empty cell" mean? Perhaps it might help if you told us exactly what you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below at http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Xnpv-Function.html

> #### #NAME? -
>
> Occurs when Analysis ToolPak add-in is not enabled in your Excel.
>   You will need to enable the add-in if you want to use the Excel Xnpv function.
>
> - Show How to Do This in Excel 2003:                                *(hidden)*
> - Show How to Do This in Excel 2007:                                *(hidden)*
> - How to Do This in Excel 2010 or Excel 2013:
>
>   - Click the **File** tab (top left of your spreadsheet) and select **Options**
>   - From the menu on the left hand side, select **Add-Ins**
>   - If the window that pops up doesn't show the 'Add-ins' list, use the 'Manage:' drop-down menu (at the bottom of the window) to select **Excel Add-ins**. Click **Go...**
>   - From the 'Add-Ins' window, select the option **Analysis ToolPak** and click OK